# What is a good desktop search tool?

Tags: software-recommendation

Beagle was my favorite. But it is not maintained anymore, afaik. And it does not work reasonably; it stops working spontaneously and does not return any result. How can I correct this problem and if it is not possible what alternatives are available?
Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One tool I can recommend is [`tracker`](http://www.gnome.org/projects/tracker/). If you install the software, it is started automatically when you log in. It updates its index as a background process. If you want to search some item, there are different possibilities:

1. **Nautilus**: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. A windows opens where you can enter your search term.
2. **GNOME applet**: The deskbar applet allows you to enter a search term and shows a listing of found things.
3. **[Catfish](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/catfish/)**: is a application which can talk with different search programs.
4. Console: enter `tracker search foobar` and tracker will start its search. Type `tracker` for a full list of available commands.

Answer (score 10):

I use [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/). It's very nice.

Comment: Recoll even has a unity lens for Ubuntu 11.10. Try [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~recoll-backports/+archive/recoll-1.15-on)

Comment: Customizable searches from command line. The backend of recoll is Xapian, the same engine used for website search apps like SOLR

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [Tracker](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/tracker)? It appears to be the replacement of Beagle in the Ubuntu Desktop and has been integrated with most applications in Ubuntu. `sudo apt-get install tracker tracker-search-tool`

Answer (score 0):

In command-line [`[s]locate`](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_locate.htm)  works like a charm.
s for secure

[`updatedb`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_updatedb.htm)`updatedb` update the database where file name are stored.

If you use locate like

```
locate foo
```

it will list files and path containing foo.

Usually, `updatedb` is executed via a cron job once a day but you can execute it to update the database as needed.