# What is the best Desktop search engine or software

Tags: software-recommendation, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best desktop search tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4498/what-is-the-best-desktop-search-tool)

I want to know which is the best software for desktop search for ubuntu 11.10
regards,
Gourik

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4498/what-is-the-best-desktop-search-tool

Answer (score 2):

Gnome-Do is pretty good and has alot of ratings provided obviously you use a gnome interface. Recoll and Catfish look good also but I have never tried them. All of these are in the Ubuntu universe repositories (can be found in the software center) for download. Try em out and give us some feedback.