# Google Desktop Search replacement in Gnome Classic?

Tags: gnome-classic, search

My employer uses Gnome Classic on her Ubuntu laptop. Until it was discontinued, she used Google Desktop Search, and is now looking for a replacement. I can't find an acceptable one, can someone help please?

It should have the following attributes:

- Works in Gnome Classic (non-negotiable)
- Searches local files and their contents, indexes quickly
- Searches Google, Gmail
- Preferably customizable to add additional functionality (like Wikipedia searching, etc)

Answer (score 0):

People there: [What is the best desktop search tool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4498/what-is-the-best-desktop-search-tool) suggests:
**1** [Tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/index.html)
**2** [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/features.html)