# What's the best way to search my file system on ubuntu with instant results?

Tags: pdf, search, indexing

What's the best way to search my file system on ubuntu and get results almost instantly? I have used *catfish* , *tracker* and the usual search tool provided with ubuntu.

*Tracker* finds nothing, *ubuntu search tool* is too slow and *catfish* most of the time finds nothing. I have a lot of PDFs and DJVU files that I want to access. In windows, there is a program called *search everything* that returns results almost instantly. I want a similar linux tool.

Please provide a detailed answer as possible as I'm a newbie in linux.
If such a tool doesn't exist in ubuntu, what's the chance that I can find such tool in other linux distribution e.g mandriva, redhat?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/4498/61218

Answer (score 10):

[Recoll](http://www.recoll.org/) can do this for you. It features full-text indexing for almost every document type you can imagine and a result overview sorted by page numbers for PDF documents.

[image]

[image]

You can install it through the software center (search for *Recoll*) or get the new newest version through the Recoll PPA (including a Unity lens/scope). First add the official Recoll repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:recoll-backports/recoll-1.15-on
sudo apt-get update
```

If you are on Ubuntu 13.04 and below you will have to install `recoll-lens`:

```
sudo apt-get install recoll recoll-lens
```

For Ubuntu 13.10 and up use `unity-scope-recoll` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-recoll
```

If this is the first time you are installing from a PPA, make sure you read these first:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

[Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

You will have to execute Recoll at least once to build your search index before being able to use the Recoll lens/scope.

More extensive documentation on how to use Recoll can be found [here](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/recoll_user_manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks,Glutanimate . I have recoll and it's useless . I don't want what's inside the documents . All I want is to type a part of the file name and I get the result fast . All the tools I have tried either do not return results at all or can only work occasionally . Catfish have worked fine once but after I restarted my computer and tried it again , it returned nothing

Comment: But you can do that as well. Just choose file type from the drop down menu ( the one that says All Items in the screenshot)

Comment: I have done that but it still doesn't work . maybe because I didn't tell the program where to search ?Does it search the whole hard disk?

Comment: You have to define where it searches. By default it searches through home only. See the documentation for more details.

Comment: Well , I have those files on some partition but I do not find the option to choose partition C , E ,F familiar in windows ?

Comment: Ok , I made it search all Hard disk however , When I click search it immediately says nothing is found

Comment: Time to go back to windows

Comment: Follow the documentation and add all of your partitions in the indexing configuration wizard. Check the option "include file names" (this option should be on by default). Then rebuild the index.

Comment: If the partitions you want to add were created by windows you will first have to mount them. Open your file manager and click on each partition so that you see the eject symbol next to them. You should be able to find them in recoll under /media/.

Comment: Anyone have this working in Ubuntu 14.04? I installed recoll from the default repositories, but do not see any relevant results in Dash. I then tried adding the repository above, but cannot install recoll-lens.

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks for your comment. With Ubuntu 13.10 and up you have to install a scope instead of a lens. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Glutanimate Thank you! It's working... this definitely makes Dash a lot more useful to me.

Comment: But I don't suppose there is any way to see the actual filenames, instead of the titles from the metadata?

Comment: @BrianZ No, I don't think there's such an option at the current time. You can always drop a feature request on [recoll's bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/medoc/recoll/issues?status=new&status=open), though (e.g.: ask for a configurable option). The developer is very friendly and responsive.

Answer (score 4):

To search for file names only - ignoring content -
you can use `locate` tool. It is very fast on searching.

```
locate '*.pdf'
```

will list all the pdf file. See the manual page for more info.

```
$ locate --help
Usage: locate [OPTION]... [PATTERN]...

Search for entries in a mlocate database.

  -b, --basename         match only the base name of path names
  -c, --count            only print number of found entries
  -d, --database DBPATH  use DBPATH instead of default database (which is
                         /var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db)
  -e, --existing         only print entries for currently existing files
  -L, --follow           follow trailing symbolic links when checking file
                         existence (default)
  -h, --help             print this help
  -i, --ignore-case      ignore case distinctions when matching patterns
  -l, --limit, -n LIMIT  limit output (or counting) to LIMIT entries
  -m, --mmap             ignored, for backward compatibility
  -P, --nofollow, -H     don't follow trailing symbolic links when checking file
                         existence
  -0, --null             separate entries with NUL on output
  -S, --statistics       don't search for entries, print statistics about each
                         used database
  -q, --quiet            report no error messages about reading databases
  -r, --regexp REGEXP    search for basic regexp REGEXP instead of patterns
      --regex            patterns are extended regexps
  -s, --stdio            ignored, for backward compatibility
  -V, --version          print version information
  -w, --wholename        match whole path name (default)
```

Comment: Note that for update the index you must run:

`sudo updatedb`

Also a powerful feature on this, is that you can save your index on a file then use it with `locate <filename> -d <DBPATH>` great option if you want to keep indexed locally HDD's but not always connected

Answer (score 1):

I also do a lot of searching through very large libraries of PDFs. For me, this is the #1 frustration of Linux that makes me miss MS Windows. I've tried it all at this point, and the solution I have settled on for now is to use the following programs in combination.

Unfortunately, none of these seem to be in the Ubuntu repositories at the moment, and may be unstable. So if Recoll (now in the default repository for Ubuntu 14.04 I beleive?) or something else works for you, better to stick with that.

**1) Synapse**

Installation: Read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449285/is-synapse-application-launcher-available) for details, but basically you can install it by running the following commands in a terminal.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:synapse-core/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Positive

- Very fast, smart search results
- If what you want doesn't come up right away, you can press down and tab to find more with "locate".

Negative

- Only searches filenames, not text inside.
- Seems to miss a lot, especially before you try "locate".

**2) Launchy**

Installation: Download the package [here](http://www.launchy.net/download.php#linux).

Positive:

- Almost as fast as Synapse
- Results are very comprehensive.

Negative:

- Also only searches filenames.
- Probably the buggiest of these three.

**3) DocFetcher**

Installation: Unless you can find it in a repository somewhere, you are stuck with the portable version. Download it [here](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/download.html) and follow the instructions.

Positive:

- Searches inside the text of your PDFs
- Comprehensive but relevant results, in a logical order (I usually find the results in Recoll or Tracker to be completely screwy in comparison)
- Full document preview pane so you can see more of the file before you open it (not just a few lines)
- Reasonably fast

Negative:

- Hard to install and run natively in Ubuntu (e.g. without Java runtime)
- Much slower than the apps that only search filenames

---

Hopefully Dash will catch up and make all of this obsolete, but in the meantime these three are mostly what I am using.

Other options maybe worth trying:

- [Gnome-Do](http://do.cooperteam.net/download.shtml) might be a worthy alternative to Synapse, but last I checked it can only index 5000 files, and that is not enough for me
- [pdfgrep](http://pdfgrep.sourceforge.net/) is sometimes useful but slow and has no GUI that I am aware of

Comment: Very comprehensive answer, +1. My only suggestion would be to give Recoll another try. Out of all solutions it's the most configurable by far. And while it might take some time to tweak to your specific needs and use case I can only say that it's very much worth the effort. Luckily the [documentation](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/index.html) is *very* good and exhaustive.

Comment: Also, from the sounds of it you are more interested in a lightweight solution that retrieves documents based on their file name rather than their contents There's a new project I saw a few weeks ago that might fit the bill. It's called [PyNeedle](https://bitbucket.org/aperezmendez/pyneedle) and uses Recoll's powerful indexer as its backend. I have yet to try it out but it might be a good alternative for your specific use case.

Comment: @ Glutanimate Thanks... Now that I have the Recoll lens working in Dash since yesterday, I've been using it quite a bit. I will definitely look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]you can also use gnome-search-tool .
you can get it by `sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool`

Comment: Yeah let us know , is it suits to your requirements or not . :D

Comment: The download is complete but how can I use it?

Comment: open your unity dash and type as gnome-search-tool , it will opens with what and where you want to do the search . look the image .

Comment: you can have lot options if you go for Select More Options , :D

Comment: I've done that . It finds nothing .However,The terminal says that the program is installed

Comment: Sorry ,I typed it "genome searching tool" :D

Comment: Cool , It doesn't work too

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code will return search results very quickly. Just change the second parameter in `fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'*.txt)` to whatever you are looking for. It's incredibly quick.

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Synapse.
Integrates Zeitgeist results.
I have a lot of documents on my system, and was surprised at how fast Synapse was able to find the files I need.

*sudo apt-get install synapse*

cheers

Comment: The Unity dash also uses Zeitgeist and seems to be too slow for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For a command line option, *"silver searcher"* is in my opinion simply the best. Far faster than `find` and `awk`, and has simpler usage:

`ag <path>`

Install from ubuntu 14.04

`sudo apt-get install silversearcher-ag`

Take a look on some speed comparisons against `find` and `awk`

https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher