# Search text within multiple pdfs and docs

Tags: pdf, search, text, doc

I got a bunch of notes written by other students, but they are from an old textbook that didn't deal with everything in the same order, so I need to search through the notes for every chapter (each individual chapter is in a different .pdf or .doc) for "trace conditioning" for example.

I used to use Google Desktop for this, I have Launchy now and I told it to search pdfs, but it only searches the titles, not the content.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Once you find a match, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you need to know if a string occurs in a file, or *where* that is as well?

Comment: Once i find which chapter covers the topic i am looking for I can read the notes on that topic in that chapter, so I just need to know IF and not where.  (Please remember when answering that I can't comment on your answers because I haven't got 50 reputation points, I can only comment on my own question).

Comment: You can comment on answers to your question, we're not *that* harsh.

Comment: @Rabbit with your edit summary you blocked me to editing your question to removing "Thanks" ;)

Comment: I don't see where it says that I can't say thanks?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[**Recoll**](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) is probably the most versatile document search engine you will find on Linux:

[image]

It supports a plethora of different formats and is very customizable.

For installation instructions and other pointers please check out [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194148/81372). [The official documentation](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/usermanual/index.html) is very useful, too.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it's native to linux, it's in the ubuntu software centre and it's all gui. In other words, this is the easiest one :D Thanks :)

Comment: Amazing app. So fast!

Comment: Don't forget to install `antiword` in order to search `.doc` files as well.

Comment: Not in the software centre for 20.04.

Comment: and you can use recolld from the terminal. also I needed to set in recoll settings gui search parameters and unclick dynamically build abstracts (which is the default) to get it to speed up to recolld's speed.  it is expensive in time waiting for the results (or I found it so, as in minutes waiting)

Answer (score 33):

Install the package `pdfgrep`

```
sudo apt-get install pdfgrep
```

then use the command:

```
find /path -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep pattern {} +
```

Comment: Can we able to configure it with gnome search engine ??

Comment: Thank you! This worked. If anyone is wondering, "pattern" is what you would replace with specific text. If the text has spaces in it, you can enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: If you know where your PDF files are, you can simplify the command to just `pdfgrep -r "my expression"` where `-r` searches recursively through directories.

Comment: Worked great for me (on ubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 6):

Use [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html), it is a native Linux application that indexes and searches through multiple document types.

Comment: Thanks! That works well, can't seem to execute it without using the terminal though. I'd vote you up but.. can't vote yet ;)

Comment: @Rabbit Um, I think you can also vote on answers to your question.

Comment: @AlaaAli No, the reputation limit applies to the OP also.

Comment: Yup, I couldn't. I can now though! :) I just needed 15

Answer (score 1):

I understand that Adobe Reader is proprietary software, but it has well designed *Search in Files* functionality (accessible from *Edit*->*Search* menu or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

## Simple Search Options

The *Simple search* window is shown below:

[image: Simple search in Adobe Reader]

You need to set *Where would you like to search?* to *All PDF Documents in* and then select location from drop-down menu (*Browse for Location*).

You can enter search item to the *What word or phrase would you like to search for?* field and specify search options: *Whole words only*, *Case-Sensitive*, *Include Bookmarks*, *Include Comments*.

## Advanced Search Options

Advanced search is more configurable - see image below:

[image: Advanced Search]

The search path is set in *Look In*.
Search item - in *What word or phrase would you like to search for?*.
*Return results containing* has options: *Match Exact word or phrase*, *Match Any of the words*, *Match All of the words*, *Boolean query*.

Other options include: *Whole words only*, *Case-Sensetive*, *Proximity*, *Stemming*, *Include Bookmarks*, *Include Comments*, *Include Attachments*.

---

Note: you can still install native Adobe Reader version 9.5.5 as described [in other thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032165/66509).

Answer (score 1):

[rga](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all) 
(or ripgrep-all) is a command line tool to recursively search all files in a directory for a regex pattern, that runs on Linux, macOS and Windows. It's a wrapper for ripgrep, the line-oriented recursive search program, on top of which it enables search in a multitude of file types like PDF, DOCX, ODT, EPUB, SQLite databases, movies subtitles embedded in MKV or MP4 files, archives like ZIP or GZ, and more.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called PdfgrepGUI. You can get it at sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfgrepgui/
It is only a GUI for the cli tool pdfgrep.

Answer (score -4):

1. first download "wine" software in your desktop
2. In this win install seekfast as link given below
3. http://seekfast.org/download-seekfast
4. you can do your work
5. its working ,if its not then plz comment me

Comment: Down-voted for suggesting wine (which means windows), when Linux solutions exist.

Comment: sorry bro but when I need it that times I use this that's why Give that suggestion.

Comment: Running windows application under ubuntu is generally not suggested. As linux is virtually virus free.   I go with @Sri 's idea

Comment: Good to know about it