# Searching multiple PDF documents with Recoll

Tags: pdf, search, okular, recoll

On windows, I use Foxit reader's advanced search to look up terms in multiple PDF documents in a directory.

I like how flawless and quick it is moving from one document to another and from one search result to another.

As I'm moving to Linux I'm trying to find alternatives.

On Linux, I couldn't find any open source reader that has the same functionality.

Recoll does the job and it's faster.

The issue is that moving from one document to another is a pain, as I should click open on every document which will open a new window.

Foxit on windows allows navigation with keyboard and open new results in a new tab in the same window. Foxit for Linux is unbearable, it laggy with an ugly GUI.

Is there anyway that I can customize Recoll to be integrated with any PDF reader (e.g Okular) to be as effortless as Foxit reader in multiple document search?

I learnt about Recoll from this question: [Search text within multiple pdfs and docs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558812/search-text-within-multiple-pdfs-and-docs).

I need a way to integrate it with Okular to have instant navigation from one document to another.

Comment: Well, there is of course Foxit for Linux https://www.foxitsoftware.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search text within multiple pdfs and docs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558812/search-text-within-multiple-pdfs-and-docs)

Comment: Foxit for Linux is unbearable. Slow and laggy with ugly GUI.

Comment: recollindex is unbearable and I will need to renice it to tame it's domination of the cpu to the point that I cannot use the machine. other than that, I love it.

Comment: I have struggled with it, it is now bearable in the indexing, but fantastic in the gui, in recoll settings, gui, search parameters, unclick dynamically build abstracts. why that is selected by default when it made a search take moments (I have lots of books) I do not know. also I have an alias to   alias rec='sudo renice -n 20 -g $(pidof recollindex)'


or alternatively if I want to thrash it

rec="while true; do sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof pdftotext); sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof recollindex); sudo renice -n 20 $(pidof python3); sleep 60; done"