# Ubuntu 20.04 - Index content of PDF, DOCX etc. for search

Tags: search, indexing

Would be handy if I could easily search the content of my documents such as PDF and DOC files. Preferably the files should be indexed to search faster.

So far I tried Recoll from the Snap store. However, the GUI seems a bit outdated.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4498/what-is-a-good-desktop-search-tool/

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ripgrep-all](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all).

By default, rga caches the extracted text, if it is small enough, to a database in ~/.cache/rga on Linux, ~/Library/Caches/rga on macOS, or C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\rga on Windows. This way, repeated searches on the same set of files will be much faster.